# MATLAB How to check if a part of character array is present in another char array?

Tags: matlab

I am traversing through a sub directory and getting name of each file with extension .txt in a character variable.

```
var1 = dir('*.txt');

%creating a loop with index i
var2 = var1.name(i); %Getting first file name
arr1 = ['C001','C002','C003','C010'];
arr2 =  ['C011','C012','C013','C014'];
```

File names are of format 'C001.txt' etc. I want to check whether file name `var2` belongs to `arr1` or `arr2` (to be more precise, part of variable `var2` or file name without extension). I could try using `contains()` but it works with strings and not chars. What is good way to do this task?

Comment: [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your approach above...

1. The line `var2 = var1.name(i);` is going to give you an error. The [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function returns a [structure array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), and if you're looping over the array you need to access the array element *first*, then the structure field:

   ```
   var2 = var1(i).name;
   ```
2. The `name` field is going to contain the file name *plus* extension. It looks like you'll want to remove the extension before doing comparisons, which you can do using [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html):

   ```
   [~, var2] = fileparts(var1(i).name);
   ```
3. When storing multiple character arrays, you generally want to store them in [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), as this makes them easier to handle and most functions are designed to operate on [cell arrays of characters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html) anyway:

   ```
   arr1 = {'C001','C002','C003','C010'};  % Note the curly braces!
   arr2 = {'C011','C012','C013','C014'};
   ```

Once you make the above changes, you can easily check if `var2` is a member of either `arr1` or `arr2` by using the (conveniently-named) [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function:

```
if ismember(var2, arr1)
  % Do something
elseif ismember(var2, arr2)
  % Do something else
end
```